# Pydantic model with Union field with one option mark as deprecated

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger-ui, jsonschema, pydantic

I have some Pydantic models with fields that are unions of different models.
I'm looking for a way to make some models of the union deprecated in my fastapi generated doc.

I can make the whole field deprecated with :
`Field(default=None, deprecated=True)`

but i find no way to do it on one of the possible values. For example in the following example, is it possible to tag SimpleUser as deprecated for the Log model and generate the doc according to that.

```py
from typing import Union

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Admin(BaseModel):
    name: str


class SimpleUser(BaseModel):
    age: int


class Log(BaseModel):
    user: Union[Admin, SimpleUser, None] = Field(default=None)
```

Comment: What version of Pydantic are you using? In the current one the `Field` constructor does not have a parameter named `deprecated`, so I am genuinely surprised, where you found this. **EDIT**: Nevermind, this is just a schema extra. Got it.

Comment: yes, i should have been more precise, deprecated is only a tag that can be used in pydantic fields, fastapi router and routes. it's doesn't have any effect beside making the doc cleaner if you still support old routes

Comment: Is the `SimpleUser` model supposed to have the `deprecated` tag _only_ on the `Log` model or everywhere it is used?

Comment: i would prefer a solution where deprecated only exist in the log model because i use it i authers router where it's not deprecated, but if it's the only way to make it work, be it

Answer (score 1):

Pydantic creates schemas of nested models by using `$ref` keys in the properties that are defined in other models. The schema will then by default have a separate `definitions` object containing the schemas referenced in it.

In your specific case the `Log` schema would look like this:

```json
{
  "title": "Log",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "user": {
      "title": "User",
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Admin"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/SimpleUser"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Admin": {
      "title": "Admin",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "title": "Name",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name"
      ]
    },
    "SimpleUser": {
      "title": "SimpleUser",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "age": {
          "title": "Age",
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "age"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The union is reflected in the `anyOf` key, with each object in the array referencing one of the models.

As far as I understand the current specification of JSON Schema, you are allowed to add other keywords alongside [`$ref`](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#name-direct-references-with-ref). Thus, I would assume you could communicate that `SimpleUser` is a deprecated option for `user` by simply adding the [`deprecated`](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#name-deprecated) keyword alongside the reference to the `SimpleUser` definition.

Pydantic allows you ultimate control over how the JSON schema is constructed via the [`schema_extra`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/schema/#schema-customization) config parameter. If you define it as a staticmethod of the inner `Config` class, you can modify it in any way you like.

So a way to implement that addition would look like this:

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Admin(BaseModel):
    name: str


class SimpleUser(BaseModel):
    age: int


class Log(BaseModel):
    user: Admin | SimpleUser | None = Field(default=None)

    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
            """Marks the `SimpleUser` option for `user` as deprecated."""
            user_property = schema["properties"]["user"]
            for obj in user_property["anyOf"]:
                ref = obj.get("$ref")
                if isinstance(ref, str) and ref.endswith("/SimpleUser"):
                    obj["deprecated"] = True
                    break
```

The output of `print(Log.schema_json(indent=2))` now:

```json
{
  "title": "Log",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "user": {
      "title": "User",
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Admin"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/SimpleUser",
          "deprecated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Admin": {
      "title": "Admin",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "title": "Name",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name"
      ]
    },
    "SimpleUser": {
      "title": "SimpleUser",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "age": {
          "title": "Age",
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "age"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The only difference to the one before being the addition of `"deprecated": true`.

I am not 100% sure, whether this schema should be understood by clients in the way you intended because I found no examples of it being used this way, but I also found no indication to the contrary and IMO this conforms to the specification. Maybe someone with more experience with JSON Schema can comment on this to (dis-)confirm.

---

### PS:

If the additional properties alongside the `$ref` are ignored by the client because it sticks to the [OpenAPI 3.1](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#reference-object) spec, you can still just set the deprecated property on the entire `SimpleUser` model:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Admin(BaseModel):
    name: str


class SimpleUser(BaseModel):
    age: int

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {"deprecated": True}


class Log(BaseModel):
    user: Admin | SimpleUser | None = Field(default=None)
```

Comment: sadly it seem that refs to schemas ignore additional properties, https://redocly.com/docs/resources/ref-guide/#no-siblings

Comment: @BastienB OK, that is the OpenAPI specification. It and JSON Schema are not the same thing. Apparently in this instance they diverge in their specifications. I added an alternative of deprecating the entire model as a workaround to my answer. Be careful when using thrid-party references. Always better to look at the actual official specification sources. I linked it in my answer.